# Java 7 bug Container.remove() removing all components

Tags: java, awt, java-7

I have an AWT Container with one immediate child, and add a new child at index 0, make it visible, validate the parent Frame and repaint. (The child is a class that extends Panel, but that doesn't seem to be relevant.) Everything is fine, and the Container contains 2 immediate children as expected.

I then dismiss the child by hiding it and calling `Container.remove(this)` from the child, followed by validating and repainting the container. On all previous JREs prior to 1.7 this works fine and the original child is left in the Container. However on 1.7 the `remove(this)` also removes the original child, i.e. it empties the Container. Calling `Container.remove(0)` has the same effect.  Has anybody got any ideas how to fix this? It looks like a horrible JVM bug.

i.e.
- At start: Container contains child [A].
- After addition of B, Container contains children [B,A].
- After calling remove(this), or remove(0), Container contains nothing: [].

While I can retrieve the original child before the `remove()`, then `add()` it back in, this inevitably causes a major repaint and unacceptable performance.

Comment: Have you looked at the Java bug reports to see if this has been reported? Can you post a small test program that shows this problem? If others here verify it, then perhaps it should be reported if it hasn't been done so yet.

Comment: It is very unlikely that you just bumped into a horrible JVM bug, although possible. Please post us some code to verify your claim.

Answer (score 2):

I think not true, I can't to simulating this issue,

Win7, JDK7_04 on my side

[image]

[image]

[image]

printout

```
run:
 Components Count after Adds :2
 Components Count after Adds :3
 Components Count after Adds :4
 Components Count after Adds :5
 Components Count after Adds :6
 Components Count after Adds :7
 Components Count after Removes :6
 Components Count after Removes :5
 Components Count after Removes :4
 Components Count after Removes :3
 Components Count after Removes :2
 Components Count after Removes :1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 minutes 14 seconds)
```

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class AddComponentsAtRuntime {

    private JFrame f;
    private Container panel;
    private JCheckBox checkValidate, checkReValidate, checkRepaint, checkPack;

    public AddComponentsAtRuntime() {
        JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 10));
        panel = new Container();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(b);
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel, "Center");
        f.add(getCheckBoxPanel(), "South");
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getCheckBoxPanel() {
        checkValidate = new JCheckBox("validate");
        checkValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkReValidate = new JCheckBox("revalidate");
        checkReValidate.setSelected(false);
        checkRepaint = new JCheckBox("repaint");
        checkRepaint.setSelected(false);
        checkPack = new JCheckBox("pack");
        checkPack.setSelected(false);
        JButton addComp = new JButton("Add New One");
        addComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton b = new JButton();
                b.setBackground(Color.red);
                b.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
                b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 10));
                panel.add(b);
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Adds :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JButton removeComp = new JButton("Remove One");
        removeComp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int count = panel.getComponentCount();
                if (count > 0) {
                    panel.remove(0);
                }
                makeChange();
                System.out.println(" Components Count after Removes :" + panel.getComponentCount());
            }
        });
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add(checkValidate);
        panel2.add(checkReValidate);
        panel2.add(checkRepaint);
        panel2.add(checkPack);
        panel2.add(addComp);
        panel2.add(removeComp);
        return panel2;
    }

    private void makeChange() {
        if (checkValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.validate();
        }
        if (checkReValidate.isSelected()) {
            panel.revalidate();
        }
        if (checkRepaint.isSelected()) {
            panel.repaint();
        }
        if (checkPack.isSelected()) {
            f.pack();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                AddComponentsAtRuntime makingChanges = new AddComponentsAtRuntime();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception may happen because an event is triggered when a component is removed and in this event handling method you still refer to component.
For example when you delete somewhere (other than in actionPeformed()) in your code the last component then still the event actionPerformed will be fired/executed. But very often the actionPerformed() method contains code to react on user actions (user clicked somewhere on the component). So, when the last component has been deleted  any reference to a component in actionPerformed() will cause an exception.

The solution to this is to move the code from actionPerformed() to e.g. mouseClicked() or another event handler depending on what you want to do.